# Incorrect Output in Filing when copying file a to file b

Tags: c

So, I am trying to copy f1.txt, to f2.txt for e.g if f1.txt is "Hello" and f2.txt is "World" then the f2.txt file should be updated to "HelloWorld" but instead it becomes this "HelloWorldÿ" .
Why is that happening ?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int ch;
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    fp1 = fopen ("f1.txt","r");
    fp2 = fopen ("f2.txt","a");
    if (fp1==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR please enter correct file name");
        exit(0);
    }
    while (ch!=EOF)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp1);
        fputc(ch,fp2);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe your code. Consider that after a number of iterations the `fgetc()` has read all the characters of the file. Your while statement will be executed one more time, it will get EOF and it will also write that to the destination file. THEN it will stop iterating. Correct code is the one below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int ch;
    FILE* fp1, * fp2;
    fp1 = fopen("f1.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("f2.txt", "a");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR please enter correct file name");
        exit(0);
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
    {   
        fputc(ch, fp2);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```